# How to retrieve data from my SQL Server table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am having issues reading the data in my table using a Web API, so to keep it simple I have a local SQL Server instance and have a simple table called `Gender`.

This how my model:

`Gender.Model`:

```
public class Gender
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    //public Language LanguageId { get; set; }
    public int InternalCode { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

I also use a `DbContext` class as follows:

```
...
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace API.Models
{
    public class APIContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Gender> Genders { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

I also configured a connection string in my `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="APIContext" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Here is my gender controller

```
namespace API.Controllers
{
    public class GendersController : ApiController
    {
        private APIContext db = new APIContext();

        // Index
        // URI GET + api/Genders
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Genders()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, db.Genders.ToList());
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

When I go in fiddler and compose the following `http://localhost:52024/api/Genders` I however receive a 200 http code but my array is blank I received this raw message

```
[]
```

Is there a step that I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can you try this one

```
Ilist<Genders> genders = null;
genders = db.Genders;
HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse<Ilist<Genders>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, genders);
return response;
```

Comment: I am missing a using statement for me to be able to use ILIST

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong !!. why do you need using statement in that method ?

Comment: It states that the ILIST is not a type so I don't have it defined, just try it again and now its not asking for ILIST

Comment: It states that the ILIST is not a type so I don't have it defined, just try it again and now its not asking for ILIST, although it does state this Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<API.Models.Gender>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<API.Models.Gender>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a casts)?

Comment: then either u can use .tolist() for dbcontext or try casting ienumerable to generic

Comment: Alright well I change db.Genders.ToList(); and it compile however for some reason I still received a blank, I think I will remake the application from scracht again, do you have a good tutorial about web api

Comment: Yeah, I have couple of them [Link1](http://bitoftech.net/2013/11/25/building-database-model-entityframework-code-first/)  [MSDN](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) [Code Project] (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/549152/Introduction-to-ASP-NET-Web-API) check these you can grasp more knowledge from those